# Can I make a command not gobble spaces?

Tags: macros, tex-core, context

(I'm using ConTeXt, but I suspect the answer will lie in plain TeX.)

I've created an environment that takes one argument `myBufferName`, and stores its contents in a buffer of that name. Unfortunately, all spaces after the argument are gobbled, and I don't know how to stop this properly. The usual gobble-stoppers, `{}` and `\`, end up in the buffer verbatim if I put them after `\dostartbuffer`.

```
\startluacode
    -- Print contents of buffer b to stdout and tmp.txt for inspection
    function printbuffer(b)
        -- Once to stdout ...
        print('====') 
        print(buffers.getcontent(b))
        print('====')

        -- ... and once to tmp.txt.
        jan = io.open('tmp.txt', 'w')
        jan:write(buffers.getcontent(b))
        jan:close()
    end
\stopluacode

% This environment stores its contents in a custom-named buffer.
% (The #1 merely allows whitespace, like this: `\startMyBuffer [name]`)
\def\startMyBuffer#1[#2]
    {% Store the name --- we'll need it when defining stopMyBuffer
     \def\myBufferName{#2}
     % ConTeXt macro that defines the \start... and \stop... commands.
     \dostartbuffer[#2][startMyBuffer][stopMyBuffer]}

%% % Hack I currently use: a dot at the end of the definition.
%% \def\startMyBuffer#1[#2]
%%     {\def\myBufferName{#2}
%%      \dostartbuffer[#2][startMyBuffer][stopMyBuffer].}
%% %                                                   ^
%% %                                                   |
%% % I later remove the dot using Lua.

% On closing the buffer, print its contents.
\def\stopMyBuffer
    {\ctxlua
        {printbuffer('\myBufferName')}}

% Test it. You'll see the first line loses its leading whitespace :-(
\starttext
\startMyBuffer[myNameIsNobody]
    Andra moi ennepe,
        mousa, 
    polutropon.
\stopMyBuffer
\stoptext
```

When you try running it, this gives

```
Andra moi ennepe,
        mousa,
    polutropon.
```

as the buffer's contents.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You define the macro as

```
\def\startMyBuffer#1[#2]
     {....}
```

To avoid the macro eating spaces, use

```
\def\startMyBuffer#1[#2]%
    {...}
```

(Note the `%` at the end. You also have a trailing whitespace at the end of the next line. Thus, a proper definition of the macro is

```
\def\startMyBuffer#1[#2]%
    {% Store the name --- we'll need it when defining stopMyBuffer
     \def\myBufferName{#2}% <<<<---- ADDED THS
     % ConTeXt macro that defines the \start... and \stop... commands.
     \dostartbuffer[#2][startMyBuffer][stopMyBuffer]}
```

If you don't want to worry about all this, use `\starttexdefinition ... \stoptexdefinition` instead.

```
\starttexdefinition startMyBuffer #1[#2]
   % Store the name --- we'll need it when defining stopMyBuffer
   \def\myBufferName{#2}
   % ConTeXt macro that defines the \start... and \stop... commands.
   \dostartbuffer[#2][startMyBuffer][stopMyBuffer]
\stoptexdefinition
```

Comment: Tried them both, they both work a treat. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The general syntax of `\def` is

```
\def<name><parameter text>{<replacement text>}
```

, where `<parameter text>` is matched against input. The parameter text can contain parameter tokens (`#1`, `#2`, …) and other tokens, for example, `#1[#2]abc`. Other tokens are matched exactly against input — in this example, if TeX fails to find a sequence `<something>[<something>]abc`, it will stop with an error. After a match has been found, the `<something>` parts will be taken as macro parameters per parameter text definition, but the other matched tokens will be simply eaten. In your case the parameter text of `\startMyBuffer` contains space after `[#2]`, thus it will be also matched and eaten.

Look at the output of this Plain TeX document to see the difference:

```
\def\readsome#1\relax{`#1'}    
\def\a[]
    {\readsome}    
\def\b[]{\readsome}

\a[]
    test\relax
\b[]
    test\relax

\bye
```

Conclusion: don't put extraneous symbols in macro parameter text. For Plain TeX/LaTeX, let `{` follow immediately after all parameters have been specified; for ConTeXt, put a `%` after the parameter text to ignore the newline and the following space.

Comment: In ConTeXt, the standard style is to add a `%` on the `\def` line and put `{` on the next line.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but you seem to indicate that you *don't* want TeX to gobble whitespace. If that's what you're after, check out the commands `\obeyspaces` (Plain TeX) and `\obeywhitespace` (eTeX).